# Setting items from a list to another list (both containing class instances) in random groups in python

Tags: python, list, class, loops

I have two lists containing instances from two classes.
I want to assign groups of items from the first list to the second. I have the right method add_agent. 
I just don't know how to iterate and exhaust both lists in the right order.

For example:
20 Agents assigned to 5 Families in random groups of 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

My code so far:

```
def allocate_to_family(families, agents):
    for dummy_agent in agents:
        for dummy_family in families:
            num_members = numpy.random.choice(4)
            while num_members != 0:
                dummy_family.add_agent(dummy_agent)
                num_members -= 1
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to achieve here? Like an example output would be great!

Comment: Family 1 (agent1, agent2, agent3); Family2(empty); Family 3 (agent4, agent5) ....

Comment: Does order matter? Do you want random agents for each family, or any order is fine?

Comment: Any order is fine. But I want to exhaust the list of agents. If there are none left for all families, none are assigned and I have some empty families.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.sample` to choose a random group of families then assign the agents :

```
def allocate_to_family(families, agents): 
    for dummy_family in families: 
        for dummy_agent in random.sample(agents, 4):                               
            dummy_family.add_agent(dummy_agent)
```

Comment: The opposite (below) seems to work. But I have repeated agents:

Comment: `def allocate_to_family(families, agents):`
        `for dummy_family in families:`
            `for dummy_agent in random.sample(agents, 4):`
                `dummy_family.add_agent(dummy_agent)`

Comment: Of course. But is it possible not to repeat the agent? @kasra

Comment: @B_Furtado Yeah fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to what you want to do. Actually I'll just modify your code to the desired effect:

```
# We go through each family
for family in families:
    # For each family, we go through the agents in the agents list
    count = random.randint(0, 4)
    assigned = []

    for agent in agents:
        # We assign 0-4 agents. If there are no free agents left then we 
        # won't assign any
        if count == 0:
            break
        else:
            count--;
        family.add_agent(agent)
        # Remove that agent once we assigned him, but we can't remove 
        # inside a for loop, so we store it inside a list to remove later
        assigned.append(agent);

    # This is a one-liner that remove elements in sublist from list I found
    agents = [x for x in agents if x not in assigned]
```

So basically, we need to remove assigned agents from the original list, otherwise they are going to be assigned repeatedly. Since we are in a for loop, we need to store them in a temporary list and remove them later, as it is forbidden to modify a list when we are looping through it.

I'd like to point out a separate solution as well. We can loop through each agent, then randomly pick a family, check if it has less than four agents, then adds the agent to the family. Otherwise try to find some other family with less than four agents. This requires you to know the current number of agents for a family, though. I assume this is `family.numberOfAgents()` in the following code:

```
for agent in agents:
    family = False

    # This loop exits after finding a valid family
    while !family:
        family = numpy.random.choice(families)
        if family.numberOfAgents() >= 4:
            family = False

    # Finally add the agent
    family.add_agent(agent)
```

Comment: Thanks @Flying_Banana. But maybe I have to add a method in my Family class that checks if the agent is already in the family. If it is, turn down the add option!

Comment: That will also work (the goodness of able to modify the classes themselves!). Simply check whether an agent is already assigned, and modify a few spots and you should be done!